# GWT: Roundtrip Example With Button Click

Tags: java, gwt

I'm having a hard time connecting all the dots with GWT's event-listener model. Let's say you have a Button widget, and when the user clicks it, you want text somewhere else on the screen from black to red (just thinking of a super-simple example).

When the user clicks the Button, a button click event gets placed on the Event Bus, which is configured with handlers/listeners that want to be notified when this event happens. How does this tie into `Place`s, `PlaceChangeEvent`s, and the GWT History API?

If someone code provide a super-simple, but *functional* code example of this "roundtrip" process, from button click, to firing the click event on the bus, to handling the event off the bus, to updating the appropriate place/history objects, and finally, changing the text to red, I think I'd be able to connect many of the currently-missing dots. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you ask is for a fully functioning project skeleton with some implemented functions. Not so easy to do here. The problem with methodologies such as these is that it all comes down to a carefully designed skeleton project. Maybe http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=Tutorial-Contacts.zip will help. It is a ready project with some impelementation that I think will help.

Comment: You don't need an EventBus in your example. You just attach a ClickHandler to your button. EventBus is useful for more complex situations when something happens in one view and you want to make changes in three other views that are not even visible at the moment, and you don't want to connect them all by using regular ClickHandlers (for example). You can build a large GWT app without ever touching the EventBus. I would recommend leaving EventBus for later, when you get comfortable with Handlers.

Answer (score 0):

GWT has many types of events and it is not easy to really understand them all. Some events occur only in logic, others come from the DOM (and can be used either in [capture or bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)), etc.

Just go one step at the time, as you seem to be trying to mix different events together. (a button click and history events are completely independent events). In general, the idea is that many classes provide different kinds of events, and you connect handler for the ones you care about. Your handlers can then call other classes or generate other events. The code that you want is actually pretty simple, this is the only class that you need in your project:

```
public class Sandbox_gwt implements EntryPoint
{
   public void onModuleLoad()
   {
      final Label label = new Label("I'm red");
      label.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#FF9999");

      Button button = new Button("click me!");
      button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
      {
         @Override
         public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
         {
            label.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#99FF99");
            label.setText("I'm green");
         }
      });

      RootPanel.get().add(label);
      RootPanel.get().add(button);
   }
}
```

You can see the "flow" if you are really interested by debugging this, but there is no need to do a "manual roundtrip" or anything. The history, BTW is a separate class to listen for the forward and back buttons in the browser itself, plus some other stuff, but is not necessary at all to do what you mention.